# Get url of website form post was submitted from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'm working on a rails application that receives information via a form from another site. I want to be able to detect what site the form was submitted from so I can setup validation to only process messages from test.com/contact for example.

In my routes.rb:

```
  match '/example', to: 'controller#action1', via: [:get]
```

The form on the other website (say its `test.com/contact` for example) sends data using AJAX to my `railsapp.com/example`

In my controller I have

```
  def action1
    puts "Hello world"
    stuff = params.keys    
    puts "****INFO*************#{stuff}*******************"   
    render nothing: true
  end
```

When I test it out and look at the console output, I can't find anything in the parameters showing where the get request came from:

```
Parameters: {"callback"=>"jQuery545332_1462068", "name"=>"something", "email"=>"something@something.com", "message"=>"something", "_subject"=>"Message something", "_"=>"1462891691071"}
Hello world
****INFO*************["callback", "name", "email", "message", "_subject", "_", "controller", "action"]*******************
```

How do i see what website the message came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im your controller you have access to a `request` object.

This has a attribute by the name of `referrer`.

`request.referrer` will get you the site the request has come from.

Comment: Thank you! I was playing with request.host earlier and couldn't find the documentation to see what else I could do with the request object.

Comment: @jtlindsey its worth noting that the referrer header can be spoofed.